# 'No Results' text in UISearchDisplayController issue

Tags: ios, user-interface, uisearchdisplaycontroller

My out of the box 'No Results' text in my UISearchDisplayController looks squished when it's displayed (I am aware that UISearchDisplayController is deprecated).

Env... 
Xcode 6.3
Supporting iOS 7 and 8
Using Storyboards
Same issue in simulator and on hardware

Any ideas on how to correct this?

[image]

Comment: I'm encountering the same problem. Did you ever find a fix?